# How to find the predition accuracy in precentage using regression model in python

Tags: python, regression, lstm

Here I tried to predict the value according to the actual value using LSTM regression model. After prediction the value I need to find the prediction accuracy percentage of predict values with actual value.

I tried but it gave me large minus value.

Here is my code:

```
pred=model.predict(x_test)
pred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(pred).reshape ((len(pred), 1)))
real_test = scaler_y.inverse_transform(np.array(y_test).reshape ((len(y_test),1))).astype(int)
pred = pred[:,0]
real_test = real_test[:,0]

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
accuracy_regression = mean_squared_error(real_test, pred) 
print(accuracy_regression)
accuracy = 1-np.sqrt(accuracy_regression)
print("Prediction Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy*100))
```

Then output:

```
394.2002447320037
Prediction Accuracy: -1885.45%
```

This is wrong. Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric. For regression, try r2_score, mean_square_error etc.

Comment: @ShwetaChandel Can you provide me some example, actually I tried and didn't come proper accuracy level., if you are okay . Thank you

Comment: Just replace accuracy_score with r2_score. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html

Comment: @ShwetaChandel Got it .thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using scikit-learn ?
So the Mean Squared Error (MSE) compute a risk metric corresponding to the expected value of the squared (quadratic) error or loss ([more informations here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-error))

If you want to know the accuracy score of your model you can use the function:

```
sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None)
```

You can find more information about metrics in scikit-learn [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)